# Is there anything in the RAW for replacing taught tricks for new ones?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

If you're trying to teach an animal a trick and the animal has a maximum of 3 tricks and already knows 3, can you replace one of the old ones for a new trick?  I can't find anyhting in the RAW about this, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will depend on what you would consider "RAW". There are ton's of supplements for Pathfinder, both on the SRD and outside it. Per the *core*, there is not a way to do this that I can figure out.

You can, as suggested by Colin D, replace your animal, or discuss a way to replace one trick for another with your DM. As always, a DM have the powers to house-rule this, so check up with him.

You can however "Push" your animal to do some tricks that it doesn't know, as a higher-CD test. [Look at this link](http://paizo.com/prd/skills/handleAnimal.html) for details on how to "push" an animal.